# Adding a tag to MenuItems while using ItemSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a menu that I populate by setting its `ItemSource` to a list of the type `TblCategory` in the view model. The `TblCategory` type is just a class that has an `Id` and a `Name` variable in it.

I set the `DisplayMemberPath` of the menu to "Name", so I have a list of MenuItems properly named and presented, however I would like to do one more thing that I don't know how to do:

id like Each MenuItem to have the `Id` of the category in its `Tag`.

I think I would have to modify the Menu.ItemContainerStyle to bind to something, but I need some guidance.

[Picture for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrc6H.png)

[Also, the TblCategory class and table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn39c.png)

[What I would like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8X0h.png)

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Making people click links is annoying, put the relevant code in the post, and include the images inline if you feel them important

Comment: Sorry, this was my first post, noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Menu ItemsSource={Binding ...}>
   <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
        </Style>
    </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>  
</Menu>
```